# can the magento2 system work without valid email address?

Tags: magento2

I have a question that can we build a magento2 application without valid email id.
the reason why I am asking this is because, I feel that a valid email id is mandatory for all the communications (for orders, updates on sipping etc etc).

so can we go ahead and build a system based on invalid address for customers?

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the non-valid emails only for development, then you dont need any valid emails. You can simply install **mailcatcher** and then whenever you send an email, valid or not, that mailcatcher will catch it and display it. However of you want to develop a store that is live and used by customers, then yes you do need valid email address.